# WordPress - вопрос по хуку

Tags: php, wordpress

Данный хук срабатывает при событии  на любой странице, где он вызывается.
Как заставить данный хук вызываться на определенной странице и больше нигде.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'reordering_order_item_totals', 10, 3 );

function reordering_order_item_totals( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ){
    global $WOOCS;
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $currency_code = $order->get_currency();
    $currencie = $WOOCS->get_currencies();

    $resS = $WOOCS->back_convert(46.20,$currencie[$currency_code]['rate'],2);
    $totals['equivalent'] = array('label'=>'Equivalent in euro', value => $resS );

    return $total_rows;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте функции `is_page`, `is_post`, `is_tax` в зависимости от ситуации